# Calculating an endomorphism ring of a module over $R = \Bbbk[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R = \Bbbk[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$, and let $M = (x,z)$. I want to determine $\text{End}_R(M)$.

Since $R$ is a domain, I think that we're able to identify $\text{End}_R(M)$ with $ \{ q \in Q(R) \mid qM \subseteq M \} $, where $Q(R)$ is the field of fractions of $R$. Obviously, $R \subseteq \{ q \in Q(R) \mid qM \subseteq M \}$, so now I'm wondering if this is actually an equality.

Comment: It follows from [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1306587/121097) that the equality holds. (Note that $R$ is integrally closed.)

Comment: Great, that does the trick!