# Necessary and sufficient conditions for Noetherian integral domain to be integrally closed

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, integral-domain, noetherian

One can show (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306526/does-textend-ri-r-always-hold-when-r-is-an-integrally-closed-domain)) that for a Noetherian integral domain, the following are equivalent:

1. $R$ is integrally closed; and
2. $\text{End}_R(I) = R$ for all nonzero ideals $I$.

Is the following condition also equivalent?

3. $\text{End}_R(\mathfrak{p}) = R$ for all nonzero prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$.

The proof of (2) $\Rightarrow$ (1) that I know (and hopefully this is correct!) is as follows:

We show that $R$ is completely integrally closed, which is equivalent to integrally closed when $R$ is Noetherian. Let $Q$ be the fraction field of $R$: suppose that $q \in Q$ is almost integral, so there exists $0 \neq a \in R$ such that $a q^n \in R$ for all $n \geqslant 0$. Set $T = R[q]$, and $I = \{ x \in R \mid xT \subseteq R \}$, which is nonzero since $a \in I$. Then we have a chain of inclusions
$$
R \subseteq T \subseteq \text{End}_R(I) = R
$$
so that $R = T$, forcing $q \in R$, which means that $R$ is completely integrally closed.

Assuming this isn't flawed, if I can show that the ideal $I$ is prime, then I'm done. However, I can't see why this should be the case.